# How do I use FB.api?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have a small application. As the page loads it displays me 'Undefined'. Why is that and how do I sort this out?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
    <head>
       <title>Facebook Stream Publish PHP example</title>

        <script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body><div id="fb_root"></div>

       <script type="text/javascript">
            FB.init({appId: 'appid', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
            var body = 'Reading JS SDK documentation';
            FB.api('/me', 'post', { message: body }, function(response) {alert(response.length);
              if (!response || response.error) {
                alert('Error occured '+response.error+"  "+response);
              } else {
                alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
              }
            });

       </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you manage to avoid the whole of http://developers.facebook.com on your way to making this question? In particular, you might find [the section on the JavaScript SDK helpful.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/)

Answer (score 5):

Change 'appid' line of code:

```
 FB.init ({appId: 'appid', status: true, cookie: true, XFBML: true});
```

the id of your application which was registered in apps.facebook.com

After you register your application at: https://developers.facebook.com/

you have the following information in your application:

```
 Summary

 App ID / API Key
 223437354380201

 Secret App
 344573e468de5de3a10b66e0704b8083
```

Replace 'appid' by the number of "App ID / API Key", which in this case would be '223437354380201 '